# Цикл $.each не выводит полученные от сервера данные

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, json

Хочу вытащить данные из сервлета, использую JSON и AJAX. Пытаюсь запустить цикл, а он не работает, без цикла все данные выводит. В чем проблема?

JS код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    openListIndex();
});

function openListIndex() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "TableServlet",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resp) {
            $.each(resp, function(indice, list) {
                alert(list.num_index);
            });
        }
    });  
}
```

Сервлет Java:

```
    //Данные показателей на текущую дату
    public String getTable()throws Exception{

        String sql = "SELECT [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].[ID_Index], [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Data, [dbo].[Index].Name,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].[Varible] AS Varible "
       + "FROM [dbo].[Report_Count_Index] INNER JOIN [dbo].[Index]  ON [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].[ID_Index]=[dbo].[Index].[ID_Index]"
            +"WHERE [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Data = convert(varchar, getdate(), 104)"; 

        Statement st = MyConnection.openConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        ArrayList<IndexReportMethods>dataTableOne = new ArrayList<IndexReportMethods>();
        while (rs.next()) {
    dataTableOne.add(new IndexReportMethods(rs.getInt("ID_Index"),

            rs.getString("Data"),rs.getString("Name"),rs.getFloat("Varible")

            ));            
            }
        return new Gson().toJson(dataTableOne);

    }

      //Данные для заполнения листбоксов
      public String getListIndex()throws Exception{


        String sql = "SELECT [ID_Index], [Name]FROM [dbo].[Index]"; 

        Statement st = MyConnection.openConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        ArrayList<IndexTableList>index_list = new ArrayList<IndexTableList>();
        while (rs.next()) {
    index_list.add(new IndexTableList(rs.getInt("ID_Index"),rs.getString("Name")));            
            }
        return new Gson().toJson(index_list);

    }

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try{

        out.println(getTable());
        out.println(getListIndex());
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        out.close();

    }


}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}
```

Пример данных, возвращаемые сервером:

```
[
  {
    "id_index": 1,
    "date": "2017-04-29",
    "name": "Коэффециент текущей ликвидности",
    "varible": 1.6
  },
  {
    "id_index": 3,
    "date": "2017-04-29",
    "name": "Коэффециент срочной или быстрой ликвидности",
    "varible": 0.9
  }
]
```

И еще

```
[
  {
    "num_index": 1,
    "name_index": "Коэффециент текущей ликвидности"
  },
  {
    "num_index": 3,
    "name_index": "Коэффециент срочной или быстрой ликвидности"
  }
]
```

Comment: Для начала показали бы что за данные получаете. Посмотреть можно в Инспекторе в любом браузере, в разделе Network.

Comment: Просто с сервлета данные считываю

Comment: А разве $.each умеет итерировать  объекты?  Мне кажется, надо обычным js обрабатывать

Comment: ну я не компетентен в этом деле, но я делаю по видео лекции, там это работает

Comment: если я пишу function openListIndex(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "get"
                ,url: "TableServlet"
                ,async: true
                ,cache: false
                ,success: function(resp){
                     
                           alert(list.num_index);
                    
                 }
            });  
        }

Comment: Данные выводятся

Comment: а какой другой цикл можно использовать?

Comment: @Данил с самой первой редакции вопроса в нём есть слово "сервлета", а сервлеты связаны с Java чуть больше чем полностью.

Comment: @splash58 [умеет](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-object-callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Провайдните `dataType`:

```
function openListIndex(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json', // <- Вот это
        type: "get",
        url: "TableServlet",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resp) {
            $.each(resp, function(indice, list){
                alert(list.num_index);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: не работает все-равно, спасибо конечно

Comment: @Serjey123 тогда смотрите что приходит от сервера.

Comment: @ AGS17 вот что приходит от сервера (добавил в описании)

Comment: @Serjey123 почему предложено два варианта? Какой из них приходит по урлу TableServlet?

Comment: @ AGS17 out.println(getTable());
        out.println(getListIndex());

Comment: @ AGS17  две таблицы одновременно выводятся, как одна

Comment: @Serjey123 в смысле? Просто к json одной таблицы просто конкатите json другой таблицы и возвращаете это?

Comment: out.println(getTable());
 out.println(getListIndex()); да вот эти два метода, они просто поочередно выводятся, оставил один все-рано не работает

Comment: @Serjey123 вставьте сюда https://www.screencast.com/t/ykYPwYAZ дебаггер и пришлите скриншот что приходи в `resp`

Comment: @ AGS17 спасибо за подсказку продебажить) в итоге ошибка в библиотеке была, поставил новую и все заработало, спасибо еще раз