# Не работает запрос и ответ от сервер AJAX JSON JavaScript Java Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, servlet

Здравствуйте. Не знаю, почему по нажатию на кнопку не выполняется запрос на сервер и не  выводит результат.

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

     $("#find_by_date").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
});

    $("#first_button").click(function(e){


        $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json', 
    type: "post",
    url: "FindDataByDate",
    data:{dateFirstQuery:$("dateFirstQuery").val()},
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(resp) {
        $.each(resp, function(indice, list){
                alert("indice");
            });
        }
    });


    });});






protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     doPost(request,response);

} protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
   String countryCode = request.getParameter("dateFirstQuery");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try{

        out.print("OK");
        out.println(getSurchByDate(countryCode));

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        out.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: "не выполняется запрос на сервер" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @ Igor сервлет работает, проверил, формулировка возможно некорректная

Comment: @Igor  сервлет данные выводит, но я просто не могу понять, почему при нажатии на клиенте запрос не  идет или же идет, но данные на клиента не возвращает, возможно я где-то ошибаюсь, вот и написал, может кто-то ошибку увидит

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(resp) {
    console.log(resp); 
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown); 
  }
});
```

Что в консоли?

Comment: POST запрос идет, в ответ пустое значение, т.е на сервере не происходит считывание данных с текстового поля, выдается ответ с пустыми значениями

Comment: String countryCode = request.getParameter("dateFirstQuery"); сюда данные не приходят

Comment: @Serjey123 Что в консоли?

Comment: http://savepic.ru/13800589.jpg

Comment: ERROR: parsererror - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @Serjey123 Я не знаю, что делает `PrintWriter`, но имею большие сомнения, что `out.print("OK");` приведет к JSON-форматированному ответу. Добавьте в `error` обработчик `console.log(jqXHR.responseText);`

Comment: out.println(getSurchByDate(countryCode)); функция формирует JSON ответ что она возвращает return new Gson().toJson(resultByInputDate);  PrintWriter просто выводит данные при запуске сервлета (если его запускать отдельно). JSON данные формируются. Проблема в том, что мне нужно ввести данные на форме html файла, передать их на сервлет String countryCode = request.getParameter("dateFirstQuery"); и выполнить функцию и вернуть данные обратно. Я просто не знаю как это правильно сделать это.

Comment: Добавьте в error обработчик `console.log(jqXHR.responseText);` и сообщите, что появилось в консоли. Вы же уже знаете, как возвращать правильный JSON - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660012.